# React testing history push using jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-router-dom, primereact

I am trying to test a menu bar, which handles routing to some pages using `history.push`. I am using Primereact [Menubar](https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/menubar) component.

```
 class MenubarComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: [
                {
                    label: "Home",
                    icon: "pi pi-home",
                    command: () => (this.props.history.push("/"))
                },
                {
                    label: "About",
                    icon: "pi pi-info",
                    command: () => (this.props.history.push("/about"))
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Menubar model={this.state.items}/>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(MenubarComponent)
```

How can I verify that when I click on a menubar button, it takes me to the correct page?

```
     describe('MenubarComponent', () => {
        it('should navigate on menuitem click', () => {
            const menubarItemsMock = jest.fn();
            const item = {
              label: "Home",
              icon: "pi pi-home",
              command: () => (this.props.history.push("/"))
           }
            const wrapper = shallow(<MenubarComponent/>)
            //??
        })
    })
```

Comment: you need to catch the element inside menuBar that has the onClick attr` as a prop
and trigger it and then check if MenubarComponent.props.history have the string you expect

Comment: I am not really sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `history` is a prop of the component, you can create a mocked history object and pass it to the component. In order to test the `command` function in the `items` array. You need to use `wrapper.state('items')` to get the `items` array in your test case, then you get access and test `command` function.

Here is the unit test solution:

`menubarComponent.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Menubar from './menubar';

class MenubarComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        {
          label: 'Home',
          icon: 'pi pi-home',
          command: () => this.props.history.push('/'),
        },
        {
          label: 'About',
          icon: 'pi pi-info',
          command: () => this.props.history.push('/about'),
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <Menubar model={this.state.items} />;
  }
}

export default withRouter(MenubarComponent);
```

`menubar.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default function Menubar() {
  return <div></div>;
}
```

`menubarComponent.test.jsx`:

```js
import MenubarComponent from './menubarComponent';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

describe('61476449', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mProps = { history: { push: jest.fn() } };
    const wrapper = shallow(<MenubarComponent.WrappedComponent {...mProps}></MenubarComponent.WrappedComponent>);
    const items = wrapper.state('items');
    items[0].command();
    expect(mProps.history.push).toBeCalledWith('/');
    items[1].command();
    expect(mProps.history.push).toBeCalledWith('/about');
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61476449/menubarComponent.test.jsx (8.848s)
  61476449
    ✓ should pass (7ms)

----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                  | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files             |   93.75 |      100 |   83.33 |   93.33 |                   
 menubar.jsx          |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 4                 
 menubarComponent.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.886s, estimated 10s
```

Comment: Thanks, but also, how the hell would anyone work this stuff out on their own?

Comment: @alex Sorry, I didn't catch you. But I updated the answer

Comment: Not at all, not a comment on your answer. Moreso a comment on the React documentation!

Comment: @alex The testing strategies of different teams are different, so there is no single answer, but you can start by improving test coverage and unit testing